# Django Event Calendar

Tags: django

Hi
I am using an Event Calendar wirtten in Django http://www.3captus.com/download/django_calendar and it is working great expect the time format is showing up wrong. Instead of showing "12:00:00" it is showing "noon" instead, can someone figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the formatting of a date in your templates then you can adjust the format easily with the [builtin date filter](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#date).

Make sure to also check your [`TIME_FORMAT`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#time-format) setting.

Comment: Time zones is also worth looking into, if OPs problem is "not showing current time in my zone". --My 2 cents